# Did Genos get more powerful than Metal Knight?

Tags: one-punch-man

In Season 2 episode 5 of the One Punch Man anime, Metal Knight fires a barrage of missiles against Elder Centipede and the monster is completely unharmed. However in the manga,

> Genos manages to make some damage to Elder Centipede with his incineration cannon, even though Elder Centipede regenerates.

Does this mean Genos got more powerful than Metal Knight?

Comment: well.... one is hit it from outside and another one is hit the centipede from inside, so... you know the logic right~

Comment: The centipede have a harder skin protect it at outside but inside is it organ only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metal Knight calls everything "weapons testing".  He's not actually trying to defeat anything.  As such it's impossible to really tell if any feat we see him display is even remotely close to his "maximum".  This is especially so given that these are always remotely piloted suits, meaning there may be dozens of them, and variations within them, that could in principle be used in concert (think Tony Stark and his fleet of suits in Iron Man 3).

Comment: May be he calls everything weapons testing because many times he is unable to make any harm. Gotta think Child Emperor's Brave Giant is much stronger than his drone